# Where does the case insensitive modifier go in this regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

In the regular expression below, where does the `i` modifier go so as to make the search terms `$searchfor` case insensitive? It seems it won't work no matter where I place it.

```
$file = 'xml.xml';

$searchfor = '(<first>|<last>|<state>)';

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$contents = file_get_contents($file);

$regExp = '/^'.$searchfor.'(.*)$/m';

if(preg_match_all($regExp, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
} else {
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

Contents of xml.xml

```
<first>Micky</first>
<last>Mouse</last>
<state>CA</state>

<first>Donald</first>
<LAST>Duck</LAST>
<state>FL</state>

<FIRST>Gyro</FIRST>
<last>Gearloose</last>
<state>MA</state>
```

Comment: Do any of the answers resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could add the case insensitive flag where the multi line is also specified `/m`

This line:

```
$regExp = '/^'.$searchfor.'(.*)$/m';
```

Could then be:

```
$regExp = '/^'.$searchfor.'(.*)$/mi';
```

Comment: ...needed this one as a close link.

Answer (score 0):

Note row `$regExp = '/^'.$searchfor.'(.*)$/m';` in your code.

It "assembles" the content of regex (`/.../`) and just after it
there is a place for options.
You put only `m` there, so just add `i`.

But it is not all. I am in doubt whether after the "initial" part you realy
need to capture **all the rest** of the line.

Try slightly changed regex:

```
/^<(first|last|state)>([^<]+)<\/\1>$/mi
```

(`\1` requires the same content as matched by the 1st capturing group).

The advantage is that the second capturing group will catch only `Micky`,
`Mouse`, `CA` and so on, **without** the closing tag.

If you want to check **which tag** was before (the first capturing
group) this solution is also more elegant, as this group contains
only `first`, `last` or `state`, **without surrounding angle brackets**.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do it. In your current regex you could just use the `i` modifier after your closing delimiter.

```
$regExp = '/^'.$searchfor.'(.*)$/mi';
```

https://regex101.com/r/31C9SK/2/

or you could use:

```
$regExp = '/(?i)^'.$searchfor.'(.*)$/m';
```

https://regex101.com/r/31C9SK/1/

which is the same but is easier for usage when regex doesn't have delimiters (`grep`, etc.).

Another approach you could take is just converting both strings to lowercase with [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).

```
if(preg_match_all(strtolower($regExp), strtolower($contents), $matches)){
```

https://3v4l.org/MsJdV